# Drag And Drop Exapandable Listview

Tags: android, expandable

I want to develop expandable Listview. In that group as well as child view is draggable.. Please help thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

[android-advancedrecyclerview](https://github.com/h6ah4i/android-advancedrecyclerview?utm_source=android-arsenal.com&utm_medium=referral&utm_campaign=1432) is library on Github for Drag And Drop **Exapandable** Listview.

Comment: @KrunalPujara child components are draggable too. see video on that page or [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=S7cSwMArjUQ) after 30 seconds draggable expandable example is shown